# Scheme - Iterating Over Two Lists

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

Hi all I am new at learning Scheme and often have issues with making parallels between an imperative language and a functional language.

For example if I had had two arrays.

```
A = [1 2 3]
B = [4 5 6]
```

If I wanted to create a new array with the elements of A multiplied by each element in B I could simply do something like (pseudo-code):

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < B.length, j++)
        arr.push(A[i]*B[j])
```

Which would give back:

```
arr = [4 5 6 8 10 12 12 15 18]
```

What would be some ways to approach this problem in a functional language?

Comment: For a *zip* of two lists of equal length, `(map * (list 1 2 3 4) (list 5 6 7 8))` is `(5 12 21 32)` in Scheme. In Haskell, `zipWith (*) [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]` `==` `[5,12,21,32]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scheme, the most common data structure is the linked list. Unless you *have to* access elements by index, it's always preferred to use lists, as there are countless built-in procedures for handling lists, that make easy to implement most algorithms without ever using an index. Just remember that for efficient access by index, using a vector would be a better idea.

Having said that, and depending on the Scheme dialect that you're using, the solution can be as simple as this (in Racket, see the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2A%2Flist%29%29)):

```
(define a '(1 2 3))
(define b '(4 5 6))

(for*/list ([x a] [y b])
  (* x y))

=> '(4 5 6 8 10 12 12 15 18)
```

Alternatively, using only standard Scheme:

```
(apply append
       (map (lambda (x)
              (map (lambda (y) (* x y))
                   b))
            a))
```

Comment: Thanks for the standard scheme + the other dialect! Helped immensely in understanding

Answer (score 0):

In Scheme and Racket arrays (array: a data structure indexed by a natural number) is represented using vectors.

```
(define as  (vector 1 2 3))
(define bs  (vector 4 5 6))
```

To make a loop-inside-a-loop we will use a variant of `for*`.
Plain `for*` works like this:

```
(for* ([a as] [b bs])
   (displayln (* a b))))
```

Here `a` runs through the elements of the vector `as` and `b` runs through the elements in `bs`. Since `for*` is used, the b-loop runs inside the a-loop.
If `for` is used instead the loops run in parallel (try it).

Now since we want to collect the element, we can use `for*/vector` which stores the generated elements in a vector:

```
(for*/vector ([a as] [b bs])
  (* a b)))
```

For efficiency reason, one can write:

```
(for*/vector ([a (in-vector as)] [b (in-vector bs)])
  (* a b)))
```

This will generate sligthly more efficient code.

However

```
(for*/vector ([a as] [b bs])
  (* a b)))
```

will also work if `as` and `bs` are lists.